# Identify New Customer in Backend Orders

Tags: php

I'm trying to save some information using `sales_order_place_after`. But only when customer is **new**.
I discovered that `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getCheckoutMethod(TRUE)` should return `register` and so this is my work...

```
<?php
public function subscribeCustomer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($observer->getOrder() instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        Mage::log("sales_order_place_after");
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        Mage::log("quoteId={$order->getQuoteId()}");
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        Mage::log("checkoutMethod={$quote->getCheckoutMethod(true)}");
        if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod(true) == Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER) {
            $subscription = Mage::getModel('mydaily/subscription');
            $subscription
                ->setCustomerId($order->getCustomerId())
                ->setIsSubscribed(1)
                ->save();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is when I'm ordering through backend.
How can I identify when customer is new in backend orders?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution,

**Create a customer order collection and filter by customer id.**
**After filter applied if collection  is count given value 1 then it should be new customer**

> ```
>  if(!is_null($order->getCustomerId()):
>     $collection =Mage:getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$order->getCustomerId());
>
>   if($collection->getSize()==1):
>   // new Customer
>   endif;
> endif;
> ```